Why do I get an error whenever I try to withdraw money from someone's account?
The backend method in Java
@PutMapping("/withdraw/{accountId}/{amountToWithdraw}")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> withdrawMoney(@PathVariable int accountId, @PathVariable double amountToWithdraw) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(accountService.withdrawMoney(accountId, amountToWithdraw, authentication.getName()));
}

The requests
const REST_API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

export const withdrawMoney = async (accountId, amountToWithdraw) => {
    return await axios.put(REST_API_BASE_URL + `/account/withdraw/${accountId}/${amountToWithdraw}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    })
}

The error I get whenever I try to withdraw money:

PUT http://localhost:8080/login net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 302 (Found)


that has probably nothing to do with the code you've posted: it looks like you're being redirected for authentication, which may not be configured properly?

You have to know if the problem comes from the code or the server config, did you manage to do a successful request with another program like Postman?

I successfully tested the money withdrawal functionality using Postman. The process works perfectly ,I manually input the accessToken in the Authorization section.
